# ASPxGridView: How to disable GridViewDataColumn when a GridViewDataCheckColumn is checked or unchecked?

Tags: callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView with the following columns:

```
<dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="ProtocolEnabled" Caption="Protocol Enabled">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltProtocolEnabled" runat="server" />
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProtocolCount" Width="0" Caption="Protocol Count">
```

The checkbox column has a template with a literal in it so I can display Yes/No instead of an empty checkbox, but that's probably TMI.  What I need to do is this:

In edit mode: When ProtocolEnabled is checked, I need to enable the ProtocolCount textbox.  When ProtocolEnabled is unchecked, I need to disable ProtocolCount and set its text to 0.

I am not asking for a step-by-step, but a general pointer in the right direction.  I would like to use callbacks if at all possible.  I also promise **I will not delete this question** as you are answering it =P.

**Update:** Thanks to answerer, I was sent in the direction I needed to go.  Here's the code I used:

```
<dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="ProtocolEnabled" Caption="Protocol Enabled" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltProtocolEnabled" runat="server" />
    </DataItemTemplate>
    <PropertiesCheckEdit>
        <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s,e) {ProtocolEnabledChecked(s);}" />
    </PropertiesCheckEdit>
</dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProtocolCount" Width="0" Caption="Protocol Count">

function ProtocolEnabledChecked(ck) {
    var x = gvApplicationServer.GetEditor("ProtocolCount");
    if (ck.GetValue()) {
        x.enabled = true;
    }
    else {
        x.SetValue(0);
        x.enabled = false;
    }        
}
```

It's clientside code instead of callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Check this for [Accessing Controls Contained within Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3922)

**To show Yes/No**

1. On HtmlRowCreated Event access control and set it's text property after finding the control in the 
   Literal literal = ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex,
       ASPxGridView1.Columns["Name"] as GridViewDataColumn, "ASPxButtonEdit1") as Literal ;
   literal.Text = (bool)grid.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "columnName") ? "Yes" : "No";
2. In Edit Row Template Do as you did as above..
3. If you want to do some client side functionality then .. create client side event  `OnClientClick`  and use checkbox client side method. chkclientinstanceName.getValue(); or other to check with it is checked or not..

these controls are client accessible so enable/ disable by using `txtClientName.SetEnabled(true/false);`

for more help go to the

```
DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors  ClientScript namespace..
```

Try this step by step .. hope it will be helpful..

Comment: You answer set me in the direction I needed to go.  I updated my answer with my solution.